# Create a queue on protected questions where low rep users can still answer

Tags: feature-request, review, protected-questions

An option should be added for lower-rep users to answer protected questions, while the answer will not yet be posted in the question. Instead, it will be placed in a queue until the question asker or a higher-rep user approves the answer. This way, people with low reputation with good information can still be helpful and answer the question.

Comment: Instead of answering a protected question, which was protected because, it encourage low quality answers, these users can just answer existing high quality question without answers

Comment: there is already a queue that helps. It is a [meta-tag:suggested-edits] queue. Anyone willing to prove that they are qualified to answer protected questions can do that by suggesting 5 edits that will be accepted by reviewers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like too much trouble, also considering that the user need only post a good answer elsewhere and just get *one* upvote.  No need to make privileged users deal with yet another queue while the user can gain the rep first to show that he/she can post a capable answer.  Plus, this will be especially bothersome in the event that spam gets put into this queue (which is one of the most common reasons a question gets protected).